# Qt - Scrolling the Text under a widget

Tags: qt, text, scroll, scrollview, qwidget

Can anyone plz try to solve my problem. i have a frame, in that am scrolling a text. now i have added 2 widgets at both the ends of the frame. Using the stylesheet i had changed the color of the 2 widgets in black color. Now my text starts scrolling above the black color of the widget. But what i want to do is, the ***text should start scroll below the widget*** and it should ***end by scrolling below the widget***. How can i do this? Hope u guyz got my question... Herewith i had attached the screenshot of my frame for your reference. Plz Help.. Thanks in Advance.!

[image]

Comment: Some code showing the structure of your components would be helpful. I guess you need to set the z-depth of the side components. Try calling raise() on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the z-depth of the side components. Try calling raise() on them.